# ffmpeg android: change the speed of video and audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on Android platform with ffmpeg, I've built the ffmpeg and run as 'run-time' command for my android app.

I've tested some function like video trim, it's working :

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vpai/in.mp4 -ss 5 -t  5 -c:v copy -c:a copy /sdcard/vpai/out.mp4
```

merge video and audio, also working:

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vpai/in.mp4 -i /sdcard/vpai/in.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a copy /sdcard/vpai/out1.mp4
```

But when I try to speed up the video, it's not working, the command is:

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vpai/in.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' /sdcard/vpai/output.mp4
```

I execute the exact same command on desktop, its working fine, but not working on the Android...

The error message:
Invalid stream specifier:"[v]".
Last message repeated 3 times
Stream map "[v]" matches no streams.

Any one can help?

Comment: I probably does not parse video stream as v, try to use number like [0:0] or [0:1] depends on your stream maping.

Comment: The complete console output from your not-working command would of course would be helpful.